# How to prove that these functions do not intersect?

Tags: functions, roots, alternative-proof, monotone-functions

I want to prove that these two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not intersect for $x>1$:
$$f(x)=\cosh \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \pi  x \left(x^2-1\right) \cosh (\pi  x)}{\sqrt{x^4+6 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)+1}}\right)$$
$$g(x)=\frac{4 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cosh (2 \pi  x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$
Both functions are greater than one and strictly increasing. Subtraction and taking derivative do not work, the problem becomes more complicated.

**Does anyone have an idea to prove it by assuming false assumption? Or to prove that $f(x)-g(x)$ has no real root?**

Any hints or suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: The argument of the $\cosh$ in $f$ is $2\sqrt{2\,} \pi x (x^2-1)/(x^2+1) \cosh (\pi x)/\sqrt{1+g(x)}$, in case that helps.

Comment: @Toffomat Thanks. That is true. I dealt with this case, but it did not help.

Comment: Asymptotic analysis revisited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that both functions are greater than one and strictly increasing, they vary so fast that I should instead consider
$$F(x)=\log(f(x)) \qquad \text{and} \qquad G(x)=\log(g(x))$$ If you plot them, you should notice that, as soon as $x > 3$, $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ looks very linear with $F(x) > G(x)$; I agree that this does not prove anything.

Now, consider a Taylor expansion of $F(x)-G(x)$ around $x=1$. This gives
$$H(x)=F(x)-G(x)=(x-1)^2 \left((\pi ^2+1)+\left(\pi ^2-1\right) \cosh (2 \pi )\right)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$  So, starting from $0$ at $x=1$, $H(x)$ is an increasing function, which, according to Murphy's principle, will go through a maximum value. This maximum is located very close to $\frac 98$ and its nature is confirmed by the second derivative test.

For sure, now the problem is : what happens for infinitely large values of $x$ ?

For the asymptotics analysis, I shall assume that, for large $t$, $\cosh(t) \sim \frac 12 e^t$. Factoring the exponentials and ignoring the terms which are divided by $e^t$, we end with

$$f(x) \sim \frac 12 e^{2\pi x} \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) \sim \frac 12 e^{2\pi x} \frac{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}\implies  H(x) \sim \frac{4}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ In other words, when $x$ is large
$$f(x) \sim g(x) \, \exp \left({\frac{4}{x^2}}\right)$$

Computed exactly  for $x=10$, the result is $H(10)=0.0400013$ !!

**Edit**

Looking at the last result, I computed as few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & x^2\, H(x) \\
 2 & 4.0859321 \\
 3 & 4.0165826 \\
 4 & 4.0052206 \\
 5 & 4.0021354 \\
 6 & 4.0010293 \\
 7 & 4.0005555 \\
 8 & 4.0003256 \\
 9 & 4.0002032 \\
 10 & 4.0001333 \\
 11 & 4.0000911 \\
 12 & 4.0000643 \\
 13 & 4.0000467 \\
 14 & 4.0000347 \\
 15 & 4.0000263 \\
 16 & 4.0000203 \\
 17 & 4.0000160 \\
 18 & 4.0000127 \\
 19 & 4.0000102 \\
 20 & 4.0000083
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and attention. I have a question. I see in Mathematica that Taylor series of $H=F-G$ around $x=1$ is always positive (there are some minus signs, but the result is positive).  Is it possible to prove it? Then, does this mean that $H$ is always  increasing?

Comment: @Sasha1988. As I wrote, thanks to Murphy's principle, $H(x)$ goes through a maximum. If you have Mathematica, use more terms in the expansion to get an ugly polynomial in $(x-1)$. Take the derivative and solve for $0$. Now, if you want fun, plot $x^2 H(x)$. It is very quicly close to $4$. Not a very easy problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: Here is the expansion for the term $(x-1)^4$, but as you see, it is not clear that it is positive. $(x-1)^4 \left\{3 \left(\pi ^2-1\right)^2+24 \pi  \left(1+\pi ^2\right) \sinh (2 \pi )+\left(-3-33 \pi ^2+28 \pi ^4\right) \cosh (2 \pi )+\pi ^2 \left(\pi ^2-3\right) \cosh (4 \pi )\right\}$. Taking derivative does not work, since it gets very complicated.

Comment: The same for other higher terms, the coefficients of $(x-1)^n$ are positive, but it is not clear. So, this can not prove it

Comment: And I do not understand how Murphy's principle worked here.

Comment: @Sasha1988. If the function was not going through a maximum, the problem will be simple. But Maurphy came ! SInce you use Mathematica, use the series expansion to the 12th order. Differentiate it and solve for the roots.

Comment: Then, what about those values of $x$ where $1<x<\infty$? This only proves that $H\neq 0$ for small and large values of $x$. Am I right?